# Looking for papers with teaching-oriented style

Tags: reference-request, education

I am looking for papers that have the similar style to Hervé Lehning's  1989 *The American Mathematical Monthly* article ["From Experimentation to Proof" (PDF link via lehning.eu)](https://www.lehning.eu/uploads/1/2/0/8/120804163/from_experimentation_to_proof_maa_1989.pdf). It's like teaching-oriented papers.

Here's what the author said about the style at the end of his paper:

> I described this small example in such detail because I think we do not distinguish enough between research and proofs in our teaching. Of course, we all know that mathematical activity requires an experimental phase. But, too often we imitate Bourbaki's way of writing, which hides the research and the trial phases completely. So, some students see mathematics as a dead science whereas mathematics is very much alive.

Comment: You can sign-up with [JSTOR.org](https://www.jstor.org/), an extensive archive of mathematical (and other) journals. (The Lehning article itself is available at [this JSTOR link](https://jstor.org/stable/2325186).) The service usually offers free access to read a handful of articles per month, but out of consideration for the COVID-19 pandemic, the limit has been temporarily raised to 100/month. ... You might also consider posting this question to the [Math Educators StackExchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).